# Код на Python выдаёт ошибку

Tags: python

```
word = input()
print(len(word))
if word >= 6:
    print(word.upper())
elif word != 6:
    print('Неправильно')
else:
    print('error')***
```

- Написать программу если длина слова равна 6 то возвести
  слова в верхний регистр и добавить в новый массив.

Делал вот такую задачку и не знаю какая у меня ошибка

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы увеличиваете регистр слова в тех случаях, когда длина строки **больше или равна** 6, хотя в условии требуется, чтобы длина была **строго равна** 6.
<sub>Плюс ещё нет массива (напомню, что в Python за него можно поставить список).</sub>

UPD: по просьбе автора прилагаю код:

```py
word = input() # вводим слово
print(len(word)) # выводим длину слова
lst = [] # создаём массив/список

if len(word) == 6: # если длина строки равна 6 (длина берётся с помощью len() )
    upper_word = word.upper() # увеличиваем регистр строки
    lst.append(upper_word)    # и добавляем его в список с помощью append
# иначе пишем elif/else и делаем что-то другое
print(lst)
```

Comment: Здравствуйте, можете показать это в коде, если вам не сложно?

Comment: @ИсхакМаданбеков пожалуйста, я добавил

Comment: Благодарю, большое вам спасибо

Comment: @ИсхакМаданбеков пожалуйста. Если мой ответ помог Вам, не забудьте отметить его как верный, нажав на галочку слева